# What's the difference between denizen, resident, inhabitant?

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

What's the difference between *[denizen](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/denizen)*, *[resident](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resident)*, and *[inhabitant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inhabitant)*?

Even if their ODO definitions suggest they *are* interchangeable most of the time, are there fine differences in meaning between them?

Comment: It seems to me that *resident* has a more positive connotation than the others: it implies a legal status of legitimate belonging. *Denizen* sounds more like what one might call inhabitants whom one sees as less than fully human. *Inhabitant* seems neutral between them. Just my personal take.

Comment: Almost dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33283/what-is-the-difference-between-citizen-and-denizen

Comment: They may be defined differently as legal terms, but there is otherwise no real difference.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Yes they are, but that doesn't answer OP's question. Though they should have shown this basic research.

Comment: @Edwin, I suspect that why she made a *comment* and not an *answer*.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald Addressing synonymity of words without addressing the polysemy of the individual words is potentially confusing. OP shows in their second sentence that they realise synonymity is not the whole issue; they're asking about the degree of overlap.

Comment: As ngram shows, *denizen* is used rarely nowadays (it had its heyday in the mid 17th century) and most often it refers to creatures.  *Resident* is a legal status: the locale it refers to is a political entity (district, city, county, state, province, etc). *Inhabitant* is a socio-cultural term, and the locale to which it refers is most often geographic  (the steppes, the desert, a mountainous region) or geopolitical (e.g. the Middle East).

Comment: You ***denizens*** of rocks and crevices, occupying towering peaks: Though you build your nest high as the eagle, from there I will bring you down--sayeth the Lord. -Jeremiah 49:16

Comment: This seems a rather opinion-based question to me.  My opinion is that ***denizens*** sounds fancy schmancy, whereas ***citizens*** and ***inhabitants*** sounds more bureaucratic.  In a hierarchy,  ***citizens*** sit on top, for like ***citizens*** of Ancient Rome, ***citizens*** are the ones with rights and entitlements bestowed by their citizenry.  An ***inhabitant*** can be no more than a disenfranchised, unentitled sqauatter.

Comment: For one, these words are not exactly interchangeable. In general English writing,  each has been in use in its own context of comfort. You need to be a **citizen** of a country to qualify for a passport, being a mere **inhabitant** will not do. Depending on the domain of application (legal, technical, political, ...), the terms may have specific definitions and usage as appropriate. Compare this with *fake (currency)* vs. *faux (leather)* vs. *false (teeth)* vs. *pseudo (intellectual)* vs. *bogus (claims)*.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) entry for the three words (plus *citizen*):

> **Inhabitant, denizen, resident, citizen** are here compared as meaning one whose home or dwelling place is in a definite location. Of these terms *inhabitant* applies regularly in nonfigurative use to animals as well as persons, and only *denizen* applies also to plants and sometimes even to words. **Inhabitant**, the least specific word, implies nothing more than an abode in a given place; [example omitted]. **Denizen** denotes one that belongs by birth or naturalization to a given locality; [examples omitted]. Originally, though now rarely in literal use, *denizen* denoted one who lives within a country (sometimes a city) as distinguished from a foreigner; later it came sometimes to be applied specifically to a naturalized alien [example omitted]. Even when substituted in literary use for *inhabitant*, *denizen* retains something of its own flavor of belonging to the locality by birth or naturalization; [example omitted]. **Resident** is not always clearly distinguished from inhabitant, especially when a town or city, as distinguished from a state or country, is in question. Often the term implies nothing more than tenancy of a room, an apartment, a house, or the like, for a considerable length of time; [example omitted]. Often, in the case of a person who has several residences or who lives mainly in a place other than the one regarded as his home, the term suggests not permanent inhabitancy but legal recognition of one of these places as his domicile, and as the place where he votes, pays his income tax, and the like; [example omitted]. In reference to a country, *resident* is preferred to **inhabitant** as a designation of an alien living in that country for a time and regarded as subject to certain taxes. [Example omitted.] **Citizen**, as here compared, ... applies to a resident of a city or town, especially to one of full age who enjoys the right to vote and other privileges; [example omitted].

*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) has a nearly identical treatment of the first three words, suggesting that the distinctions didn't change much (in MW's opinion) over the intervening 42 years.

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word: A Modern Guide to Synonyms* (1968) doesn't discuss any of these noun forms, but it does make some interesting observations about the related verb forms *reside* and *inhabit* (considered as part of a larger group of verbs that also includes *dwell*, *live*, *occupy*, and *settle*):

> **Reside** is the most formal term in the group and is preferred to any of the others when a legal and permanent abode is being emphasized. [Examples omitted.] *Reside* may also suggest a tenancy  of an elegant or imposing home: ...
>
> ...
>
> **Inhabit** carries less of the implication of having a fixed abode than do *reside* and *live*. When used in this sense it tends to sound high-flown or archaic. Rather it points to people or animals *living* in large areas or adapted to specific physical environments. [Examples omitted.] *Inhabit* may also lay stress on the using of a place as a home or shelter: ...

Hayakawa's treatment suggests some similarities between the verbs *reside* and *inhabit* as he describes them and the nouns *resident* and *inhabitant* as Merriam-Webster treats them—in particular, the stronger legal aspect of *reside/resident* compared to *inhabit/inhabitant*. But in everyday use, the main difference I see between *resident* and *inhabitant* is that the latter more strongly suggests year-round domicile in the specified place, whereas the latter has a broader reach and may refer to year-round or temporary domicile, as in "She is a winter resident of Phoenix."

---

With regard to the dictionary's observation that *inhabitant* and *denizen* are sometimes applied to animals as well as persons, I note that Shakespeare memorably uses *citizen* in the same way, in *As You Like It* (act II, scene II), where a lord in the banished duke's circle reports the reaction of Jaques to encountering a mortally wounded deer in the forest of Arden:

> "Poor deer," quoth he, "thou mak'st a testament/As worldlings do, giving thy sum of more/To that which had too much:" then, being there alone,/Left and abandon'd of his velvet friends;/"'Tis right," quoth he; "thus misery doth part/The flux of company:" anon, a careless herd,/Full of the pasture, jumps along by him,/And never stays to greet him;/"Ay," quoth Jaques, "Sweep on, you fat and greasy **citizens**;/'Tis just the fashion: wherefore do you look/Upon that poor and broken bankrupt there?"

Here, of course, the choice of *citizens* emphasizes the similarity in conduct between the herd of deer and the herd of men that Jaques implicitly compares them to, both as to their velvet and greasiness and as to their lack of fellow feeling.