# Difference in use of "denizens" versus "residents"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between "denizens" and "residents"?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.  There are many where this is not the case, but reasonable research, such as dictionary definitions, should accompany questions, with an explanation as to why this doesn't provide a complete answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, a potentially interesting question can be penalised. See [*Beyond that, I think that imposing the "show research" requirement has made it harder for questioners to ask questions of the type that Yoichi Oishi has asked for many years here, without being gadded by demands to show what they've already found out elsewhere in trying to answer their own question.*](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11379/44619)

Comment: You need to explain "why" you are asking, and why are you are confused. Denizen has other meanings which may or may not be relevant here. Are you looking for a general difference in meaning or a a legal definition? I answered because I thought the question was interesting, and in the process, I also learnt something new today, the history of denization.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, in British English, a **[denizen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/denizen)** referred to an immigrant (a resident alien) who resided on foreign soil ‘*The denizen was not a citizen nor an alien: but had a status akin to permanent residency today.’*

> Late Middle English **deynseyn**, via Anglo-Norman French from Old French *deinz* ‘within’ (from Latin *de* ‘from’ + *intus* ‘within’) + *-ein* (from Latin *-aneus* ‘*-aneous*’). The change in the form of the word was due to association with *citizen*.
>
> (English Oxford Dictionaries)

A **[resident](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resident)** is usually someone who lives at a fixed abode or permanent address. You can have a *[residence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence)* in numerous locations but you can only be called a *resident* if you spend considerable time in one of these homes.

*“He entered the United States in 1988 as a permanent resident because of his marriage to a U.S. citizen.”* ([CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resident))

Delving into [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denization), we find [the following is an abstract]

> - **Denization is an obsolete or defunct process in […] Great Britain, the United Kingdom,** and the British Empire, dating back to the 13th century, by which an alien (foreigner), through letters patent, became a denizen, thereby obtaining certain rights otherwise only normally enjoyed by the King's (or Queen's) subjects, including the right to hold land.
> - The status of denizen allowed a foreigner to purchase property, although a denizen could not inherit property. Sir William Blackstone wrote "A denizen is a kind of middle state, between an alien and a natural-born subject, and partakes of both." The denizen had limited political rights: he could vote, but could not be a member of parliament or hold any civil or military office of trust.
> - **The term *denizen* may also refer to any national of a country, whether citizen or non-citizen, with a right to remain in and return to the country.** In the United States, before they were made citizens by statute, unassimilated Native Americans, although born on U.S. soil, were not deemed to be citizens of the United States or any state, but of a domestic dependent nation contained within the United States but whose members are not even nationals of it, but denizens of it, with a right to remain in and return to their reserved territories.